# Check What Version of RAID I am Using

Tags: windows-7, raid

How can I check what version of RAID I am using on a windows 7 computer? I have two drives in raid but I do not know if it's raid 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the size of the individual HD's? You could derive it from that

With RAID 1, the total size that you see in windows will be the size of a single disk (the smaller one, if they differ..)

With RAID0, you will have the sum of both disk-capacities (or twice the size of the smaller one, depending on RAID implementation..)

This is assuming you use Full-Disk-RAID
Otherwise its hard to figure out a definitive answer w/o knowing details about the RAID (Software vs Hardware, which RAID-Controller, etc)

Comment: My C drive is 2TB big, that's all I know. I can't check the individual drives.

Comment: YOu can see how big the individual drives are when you boot. It will be both in the BIOS itself and it is usually printed on the screen. (The [pause] button is your friend).

Comment: @Hennes Yes, that would be the easiest option w/o looking inside the case.  
If the BIOS is configured not to show you any POST-Messages, just some Manufacturer-Logo, usually pressing ESC displays the text

Answer (score 0):

If you see 2TB as final size for your disk in Windows, you probably have a RAID0.

For a RAID1 with 2TB final size you must have 2 physical HDDs with 2TB storage minimum. If you bought two HDDs in that size, you probably would remember that as they are fairly expensive compared to 1TB drives.

Also, with what did you set up your RAID? you might just have a look there...

Comment: Got the computer on Dell.com, it is a really powerful computer and I remember being asked which RAID type I wanted and they where included in the price. It was two years ago now. I figure it could be either RAID 1 or 0. Now I use RIAD all the time, then I had no idea.